# How do I make an Android library for static linking that includes resources?

Tags: android

I am successfully linking some of my code stored in a .jar-based library to my Android app. The .jar code references Android library content just fine.

The problem is I need to include 'res' resources in the library but can't work out how to do this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This discussion http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=30725 indicates this isn't currently possible.